# CRUD operation, EntityFramework: Passing TextBox value(Text) to a method that takes class object as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am performing CRUD operations using EF. I have an entity defined as Person_T and this is passed as a parameter to a method that performs update operation.

```
public void UpdateEmployeeDetails(int personID, Person_T employee)
    {
        Person_T emp = new Person_T();

        emp = Context1.Person_T.Where(x => x.Person_IDNO == personID).FirstOrDefault();

        emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
        emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
        emp.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        emp.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        Context1.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I am retrieving the TextBox values for the fields in my CodeBehind file as follows:

```
protected void UpdateDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            dtobj.firstNmae = TextBoxFN.Text;
            dtobj.lastName = TextBoxLN.Text;
            QS = Request.QueryString["ReqID"];
            inte = Convert.ToInt32(QS);
            OBJECTCONT.UpdateEmployeeDetails(inte,TextBOXValues );

        }

    }
```

I do not yet know how I can pass these TextBox values to the UpdateEmployeeDetails() method. The Person_T has the following definition:

```
public partial class Person_T
{
    public int Person_IDNO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Address_IDNO { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Address_Table Address_Table { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that I might not be using the best programming practices, but it would be of great help if someone could shed some light on this matter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of Person_T as below and pass it into UpdateEmployeeDetails():

```
Person_T _person = new Person_T(){
     FirstName = TextBoxFN.Text,
     LastName = TextBoxLN.Text,
     //assign other values as above
};
```

and then call the method:

```
OBJECTCONT.UpdateEmployeeDetails(inte,_person);
```

Complete code:

```
protected void UpdateDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
             Person_T _person = new Person_T(){
                  FirstName = TextBoxFN.Text,
                  LastName = TextBoxLN.Text                      
             };

            QS = Request.QueryString["ReqID"];
            inte = Convert.ToInt32(QS);
            OBJECTCONT.UpdateEmployeeDetails(inte, _person);    
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly and even updated the records. So once I Create the object I can pass as many values as I want right?

Comment: Yes, you can assign values to the properties of your object like that.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to do this?

```
OBJECTCONT.UpdateEmployeeDetails(inte,dtobj);
```

Comment: That was my first approach. Throws a "Invalid argument" error.

    Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ModelClass.ContextClass.UpdateEmployeeDetails(int, ModelClass.Person_T)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Where is `dtobj` declared?

Comment: Its declared within the parent class IndividualDetails. Which is the CodeBehind of the IndividualDetails.aspx page.

Comment: No its an instance of DataTransferObject class. Your question actually made me realize my mistake and why it wasn't working. Thank you